# My reactJs code prints a value twice in console when using console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console

Making my first project in react but getting console printed twice.

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default function App() {


  const [searchText ,setSearchText]=useState("");
  console.log(searchText); 


  //api key

  function searchForOrder(){
    //set up correct api call
    var APICall= `http://lookup-app.teflon.order-services.com/orders-lookup/services/v4/orders?orderNo=${searchText}`;
    console.log(APICall)
    //handle api call
    axios.get(APICall)
      .then(function (response) {
        //success  
        console.log(JSON.parse(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div className='template'>
      <div className='search'>
          <div className='form-control'>
            <label htmlFor='number'>Search your order Number</label>
            <input
              type='name'
              name='OrderNo'
              id='OrderNo'
              value={searchText}
              onChange={e => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button onClick={searchForOrder} className='submit'>search</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My console looks like this:
[every number getting printed two times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBE6m.png)

Can somebody please let me know where I am going wrong because , I haven't worked in reactJs before.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the re-rendering of components, React renders each components multiple time, Call console.log inside of useEffect hook and pass the searchText vaiable inside the useEffect dependency array.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(searchText); ;
}, [searchText]);
```

P.s: Don't forget to import useEffect from react before using it.